# Problems with the Parent Form in MDI Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, mdi, mdiparent

i am using Buttons as controls in the Container ( Parent Form ) 
and when the Child form appears the Controls in the Parent Form ( Button , Picture , label ) appears on the Child form and Cover it and i cant see the child Form 
do any one know how to prevent this ,, and i don want to make these controls as

`Control.Visible=false;`

cuz when i minimize the child form i want the user to get the ability to see the Container with all the controls

Comment: How are you making the child forms?  It seems to me like you're making child forms that are of the same type as the parent.  Tell us how you're instantiating the child form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the child control another container or a seperate form? If it is another container use whatever the name of the child form and bringtoFront i.e. `child.BringToFront();`  I think your problem is that you are putting controls in the parent container. They will remain on top of any mdi Child forms that you create. I think the best way for you to handle this is to change their visibility based on the window state of the mdi Child form either by creating a custom event in the Child form or monitoring the window state of the child form in the parent.